# Creating dialogue box pop up - Android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, popup

Relatively new to the whole javascript scene -trying to create my first app!
So far I have managed to create the base layout, link button to next .xml, etc. however I'd really like a button that when clicked, opens a pop-up with some information on (a few lines describing the app's purpose).
Unfortunately, all tutorials, although helpful, don't explain where in the mainactivity.java (e.g.) I need to place the code (i.e. before what tag? what do I need to keep/replace?)
I'll paste my full code for activity.xml and full for mainactivity.java - hopefully, you legends will be able to give me a steer!

Java:

```
    package com.example.newapp;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openactivity_tasks();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openactivity_tasks(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_tasks.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.09"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/shortlogo"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circlebutton"
    android:text="@string/hit_me"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.711" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Design and What2Do owned by Armourtal Ltd 2021"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.092"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Version 0.0.1"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.963"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:text="This is a popup window."
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in Java File

```
  private void showInfo() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
        builder.setMessage("Put your piece of information HERE");
    
        // Create and show the AlertDialog
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
  }
```

Add this code in your styles.xml to change text and background color

```
  <style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <!-- textColor. -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000</item>
        <!-- background Color. -->
        <item name="android:background">#fff</item>
  </style>
```

Use the method showInfo() inside your Button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          showInfo();
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the trouble I'm having (sorry) is exactly where in my code to put the above. When someone says "show method inside your button", is that on teh .xml or .java page?

Comment: Show your method inside the button in your Java File as I did in the example.

Comment: When i add "showinfo()" to my current button, the popup only shows when i click the original button - which obvs isn't supposed to happen. How do i add this to say "button1"? >>> EDIT - I've got it working, thank you so much!